# Android RadioGroup click listener

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I have definiation below of radiogroup with radiobuttons. How properly implement onClickListener ? I got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I don't know what is wrong.

```
 public void createRadioButton(Integer amount, LinearLayout layout, Integer text) {

    AppCompatTextView txt = new AppCompatTextView(activity);
    AppCompatButton btn = new AppCompatButton(activity);
    btn.setText("Click");
    txt.setText(text);
    final AppCompatRadioButton[] rb = new AppCompatRadioButton[amount];
    final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(activity);

    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

    for( i=0; i<amount; i++){
        rb[i]  = new AppCompatRadioButton(activity);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rb[i].setText("Test " + i);
    }
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            rb[i] = (AppCompatRadioButton) activity.findViewById(selectedId);

           Toast.makeText(activity, "VALUE" rb[i].getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    layout.addView(txt);
    layout.addView(rg);
    layout.addView(btn);
}
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for( i=0; i<amount; i++){
        rb[i]  = new AppCompatRadioButton(activity);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rb[i].setText("Test " + i);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            rb[i] = (AppCompatRadioButton) activity.findViewById(selectedId);

           Toast.makeText(activity, "VALUE" rb[i].getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to add a onclicklistener for each item that you loop over, you need to extend your for loop so it also iterates over your onclicklistener, like this.

Comment: I got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5

Comment: By doing you're modifying the last action button of your group and recreating a new listener. Basically, If you click on any button you'll override the last button

Comment: @Jejefcgb Not sure what you mean - but since the onclicklistener won't call the for loop, this won't happen, this for loop only runs when the radiobuttons are created. I could have misunderstood you, and if so I apologize.

Comment: Onclick won't call the for loop but everytime you create a new AppCompatRadioButton, you're setting an onClickListerner on the "btn". you just have to set this listener once after the loop. It's kinda hard to explain in a few sentence, maybe the code I posted will help you to understand what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

use setOnCheckedChangeListener for radiogroup

use like this

```
radiogroup_gender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    switch (checkedId){
                        case R.id.radiobutton_male :
                             break;
                        case R.id.radiobutton_female :

                            break;
                        default:
                             break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

After the loop your `i` values will be equal to `amount` and you are using the same `i` here `rb[i] = (AppCompatRadioButton) activity.findViewById(selectedId);`
and your list size equal to `amount-1` this is why you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: so how to resolve this problem?

Comment: depending on what you want to do, if you want to use it the same variable (i) values put your code inside the loop else chose other variable name

Comment: I resolve it by below code:     final int finalI = i;
 rb[finalI] = (AppCompatRadioButton) activity.findViewById(selectedId);

Comment: As i explained in my post, by doing this you're overriding your last radiobutton everytime you click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code. First your parameter text should be a "String", not an integer. However, the main problem in your code is that you're overidding the last radioButton ( rb[i] ) with your code. You shouldn't do this.
The best way to do it is to declare your variable i in the loop and to create a new RadioButton when the user clicks on it.

Ps : The solution you validated is unefficient as it creates a click listener everytime you create a button. Or it always update the same listerner because you only have one button.

Try the following code ;)

```
public void createRadioButton(Integer amount, LinearLayout layout, String text) {

    AppCompatTextView txt = new AppCompatTextView(activity);
    AppCompatButton btn = new AppCompatButton(activity);
    btn.setText("Click");
    txt.setText(text);
    final AppCompatRadioButton[] rb = new AppCompatRadioButton[amount];
    final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(activity);

    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

    for(int i=0; i<amount; i++){
        rb[i]  = new AppCompatRadioButton(activity);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setId(i + 100);
        rb[i].setText("Test " + i);
    }
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            AppCompatRadioButton button= (AppCompatRadioButton) activity.findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(activity, "VALUE" +  button.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    layout.addView(txt);
    layout.addView(rg);
    layout.addView(btn);
}
```